# Load Specific Image From Path After It Was Saved To Camera Roll

Tags: ios, swift

I use UIImagePickerController to save image to photo album which was taken by camera.

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(myImage, self, #selector(saveimage(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
```

The image is successfully saved to photo album with name like *IMAGE_4000.JPG*. I want to get the path to load the image directly without picking it implementing UI-based user selection.

I tried to do the following, but it only gives me access to the app's specific folder (like */var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/3C739746-<...>/Documents/*) and not to photo album.

```
let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)
let fullpath = path[0].appending("/IMAGE_4000.JPG")
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: fullpath)
let imagedata = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
let imagefromstorage = UIImage(data: imagedata!)
```

So my question is, how can I get the image name after it was saved via *UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum* and the photo album path to access it like I described in the above code snippet?

Comment: use photos framework to get album

Comment: @karthikeyan Thanks, I'll take a look to the photo framework. However, the questions remains how to get the image name firstly?

Answer (score 0):

`UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` will save the image to the `Camera Roll` album. which is a different container.

`let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)`

and the above statement will search the file in your App container.

So both are different things.

Comment: Thanks, I know they are different containers. The question is how I can get the image name and the image path after it was saved to camera roll?

Comment: if you save an image with the name "IMAGE_4000.JPG" that doesn't mean `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` will use your name. When you fetch images using Photos framework it will return different application scope name.

Comment: You can only fetch image using a name if you write the image in FileManager before you write in `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum`.